# PYSNMP TRAP/Inform Receiver is Crashing with PYSNMP 4.3.4 and 4.3.3

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

The Pysnmp Trap Receiver is crashing with PYSNMP-4.3.4 same with 4.3.3
With 4.3.2 it was working just fine.Iusse is reproducible every time.
And occuring when agent is issuing **multiple trap messages** simultaneously.

like with this you won't see the error:

```
snmptrap -v3 -u user_auth1 -l noAuthNoPriv -e 80000F150000000000000000 127.0.0.1:1036 123 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1
```

When by agent HW is sending the more than one trap message this issue is reproducing.

Refer the below code used to reproduce the problem,

```
    from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
    from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
    from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
    from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c
    from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler, rfc1902, error
    from pysnmp import debug 
    debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))
    snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()
    config.addTransport(
        snmpEngine,
        udp.domainName,
        udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 1036))
    )

    config.addV3User(
        snmpEngine, 'user_snmp1234',
        config.usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol, 'authkey1',
        config.usmDESPrivProtocol, 'privkey1',
        securityEngineId=v2c.OctetString(hexValue='80000F150000000000000000')
    )

config.addV3User(
    snmpEngine, 'user_auth1',
    securityEngineId=v2c.OctetString(hexValue='80000F150000000000000000')
)

    mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
    custom_mib_path= <provide the MIB Path>
    compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=custom_mib_path.split(","))
    mibViewController = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)
    load_mib_module = <PROVIDE the MIB Modules>
    for mibs in load_mib_module.split(","):
        mibBuilder.loadModules(mibs)

    def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
              varBinds, cbCtx):
        print "#######################Recived Notification from {} #######################".format(snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.getTransportInfo(stateReference)[-1][0])
        execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext(
            'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request'
        )
        #print "########### execContext {}".format(execContext) 
        print('Notification from %s, ContextEngineId "%s", ContextName "%s " SNMPVER "%s" securityName "%s"' % ('@'.join([str(x) for x in execContext['transportAddress']]),contextEngineId.prettyPrint(),contextName.prettyPrint(), execContext['securityModel'], execContext['securityName']))
        for oid, val in varBinds:
            output = rfc1902.ObjectType(rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(oid),val).resolveWithMib(mibViewController).prettyPrint()
            print output

    ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1) 
    try:
        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
    except:
        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
        raise
```

When receiving multiple TRAP messages it's throwing exception like:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
      File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py", line 50, in runDispatcher
        raise PySnmpError('poll error: %s' % ';'.join(format_exception(*exc_info())))
    pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: poll error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py", line 46, in runDispatcher
        use_poll=True, map=self.__sockMap, count=1)
    ;  File "/local/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 220, in loop
        poll_fun(timeout, map)
    ;  File "/local/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 201, in poll2
        readwrite(obj, flags)
    ;  File "/local/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 123, in readwrite
        obj.handle_error()
    ;  File "/local/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 108, in readwrite
        obj.handle_read_event()
    ;  File "/local/python/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 449, in handle_read_event
        self.handle_read()
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dgram/base.py", line 163, in handle_read
        self._cbFun(self, transportAddress, incomingMessage)
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/base.py", line 70, in _cbFun
        self, transportDomain, transportAddress, incomingMessage
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/engine.py", line 154, in __receiveMessageCbFun
        self, transportDomain, transportAddress, wholeMsg
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc3412.py", line 421, in receiveMessage
        PDU, maxSizeResponseScopedPDU, stateReference)
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/ntfrcv.py", line 99, in processPdu
        contextName, varBinds, self.__cbCtx)
    ;  File "<stdin>", line 10, in cbFun
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 865, in resolveWithMib
        self.__args[1] = self.__args[0].getMibNode().getSyntax().clone(self.__args[1])
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc1902.py", line 203, in clone
        return univ.OctetString.clone(self, *args, **kwargs).setFixedLength(self.getFixedLength())
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 881, in clone
        value, tagSet, subtypeSpec, encoding, binValue, hexValue
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 833, in __init__
        base.AbstractSimpleAsn1Item.__init__(self, value, tagSet, subtypeSpec)
    ;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 176, in __init__
        value = self.prettyIn(value)
    ;  File "/tmp/pip-build-K5McN0/pysnmp/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-TC.py", line 273, in prettyIn

;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 107, in isSuperTypeOf
    self._tagSet.isSuperTagSetOf(other.getTagSet())) and \
;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/tag.py", line 177, in isSuperTagSetOf
    if self.__superTags[idx] != tagSet[idx]:
;  File "/home/user/VIRT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1/type/tag.py", line 142, in __getitem__
    if isinstance(idx, slice):
;RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed in PYSNMP 4.3.5.
https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/46